# Not Able To Access The Element Using Keypress In Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am new to dom manipulation , here I am trying to change the colour of the smallest box using the arrow key. I am able to access the same using the click events.

```
   <body>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="main-box" id="main-box">
                <div class="moving-box" id="moving-box">
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

```
const box = document.getElementById("moving-box");
const mainBox = document.getElementById("main-box");

box.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 38) {
        box.style.backgroundColor = red;
    }
})
```

Comment: make sure that your `moving-box` is in focus when you pressing key, otherwise the event won't fire.

Comment: Actually you need to use document for fire event on body. Because without focus on element you can't fire event on element. 

const box = document.getElementById("moving-box");

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 38) {
        box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
});

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL comment is the answer. that's what i always do when i want to get keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `keypress` event for the keyboard arrows because

> The keypress event is fired when a key that produces a character value is pressed down.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

So we should probably use `keydown`, also you aren't clear whether you want to execute the event handler with the box focused or not. If focused you need `tabindex="0"` so the box could receive focus. Otherwise add the event listener to `document.body`.

Also note that the keyboard keys scroll the page. So you should call `event.preventDefault()` to halt that.

```js
const box = document.getElementById("moving-box");
const mainBox = document.getElementById("main-box");

box.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 38) {
        box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

```css
#moving-box{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  outline:none;
}

#moving-box+*{
  display:none;
}
#moving-box:focus{
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
#moving-box:focus+*{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Click the box to focus
    <br/>
    <div class="main-box" id="main-box">
        <div class="moving-box" tabindex="0" id="moving-box">
         </div>
         <div class="info">Press arrow up</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is event.keyCode is deprecated, you should try event.key (ArrowRight, ArrowLeft, ArrowUp, ArrowDown)

Further info: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_key.asp